# How to add mask to image when replacing images in pdf with pdfbox

Tags: java, image, pdfbox, image-replacement

I need to replace the images in the PDF document which I can do. However, after extracting and replacing the resource image object, PDF images become corrupted if there is a soft mask or mask(stencil image) in the image, mask is lost.

This is my code (used pdfbox via python with jpype):

```
for page in pages:
    resources = page.getResources()
    if resources:
        pageImages = resources.getXObjectNames()
        for c in pageImages:
            imageObj = resources.getXObject(c)
            if isinstance(imageObj, PDImageXObject):
                bImage = imageObj.getImage()
                suffix = str(imageObj.getSuffix())
                tmp = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix="." + suffix, mode="wb")
                out = FileOutputStream(tmp.name)
                if bImage.getColorModel().hasAlpha():
                    target = BufferedImage(bImage.getWidth(), bImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB)
                    g = target.createGraphics()
                    g.fillRect(0, 0, bImage.getWidth(), bImage.getHeight())
                    g.drawImage(bImage, 0, 0, None)
                    g.dispose()
                    ImageIOUtil.writeImage(target, suffix, out)
                else:
                    ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bImage, suffix, out)
                
                newImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile(tmp.name, pdf)
                resources.put(c, newImage)
                tmp.close()
```

In the above example code even if i didn't touch extracted image and immediately replace it with extracted one if image has mask it's gone after that. I can get smask like this to check:

```
imageObj.getSoftMask()
```

How can i replace image and apply original image mask to newImage PDImageXObject using pdfbox? There is "applyMask" function in PDImageXObject but it is private.

Comment: But i don't modify extracted image, just replace it with saved one. So when ImageIOUtil.writeImage saves the image doesn't apply mask to it right?

Comment: The mask is the alpha part of an image and is part of the image XObject, even if it is possible to read it separately (because it's also an object of its own). You should replace an ARGB object with another ARGB object. Re `ImageIOUtil.writeImage` it depends what format you are using. JPEG doesn't have alpha IIRC. Consider including your PDF before and after.